# doctrine2 arraycollection count() php

Tags: php, doctrine, doctrine-orm, arraycollection

i have the following code:

```
        $countries = $em->getRepository("country")->findAll();
        $array = array();
        $count = 0;
        foreach($countries as $country){
            if(is_object($country)){
                if($country->getCompaniesCount() > 0)
                $array[$count] = $country;
                $count++;
            }
        }
```

And the "getCompaniesCount" function which is called looks like this:

```
    public function getCompaniesCount(){
        return $this->_comapanies->count();
    }
```

but it produces an error which i cannot understand.

There ARE countries in "country", and there ARE "companies" which are related to countries.
so country and company is a ManyToMany-Relationship. And the attribute "_companies" in "country" is initialised as an ArrayCollection to hold the companies.

But everytime i run this code i get the following error:

```
Catchable fatal error: 
Argument 1 passed to   Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\DefaultQuoteStrategy::getJoinTableName() must be an array, null given, 
called in /usr/share/pear/Doctrine/ORM/Persisters/BasicEntityPersister.php on line 965 
and defined in /usr/share/pear/Doctrine/ORM/Mapping/DefaultQuoteStrategy.php on line 86
```

does anyone have an idea why?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

ohhh noooo. i feel so dumb. 
just a wrong foreign-key-name -.-.

solved.